# Postgres gem won't install on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to get Ruby on Rails working on my computer but the pg gem keeps failing. I have found a lot of other questions saying that you just need to use the `libpq-dev` package from `apt` and that should fix it but it is still saying that it can't find the library.

```
nicholas@nick-ubuntu:~$ gem instal pg -- --with-pq-lib=/usr/lib
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/nicholas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pq-lib=/usr/lib
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/nicholas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /home/nicholas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pg-0.14.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/nicholas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Awhile back, I found I had to use the ruby-pg gem instead of the pg gem, which was unneeded.  Also, avoid the old postgres gem.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the following packages:

`postgresql` and `libpq-dev`.

That gets the pg gem to compile the native extensions for me on 11.10, 12.04 and 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Installing `postgresql` and `libpq-dev` did the trick for me too.